# Access snakemake expand-ed variables in a script

Tags: snakemake

I often have a snakemake rule like the following:

```
rule aggregate:
    input: expand("samples/{sample}/data.txt", sample=samples)
    script:
         "scripts/aggregate.py"
```

This gives `aggregate.py` the correct list of sample data files in `snakemake.input`, but it loses the association between samples and their files. I usually need the association `sample -> sample file` in `aggregate.py` and to get it in `aggregate.py` I either (A) recreate the list of files or (B) recreate the list of sample IDs in the same order as the files. Both are unsatisfying due to duplication of data and requiring that two places of code be kept in sync if either changes.

If like this example, there's only one variable being expanded, then adding it to params is OK, i.e. `params: samples` then zipping that together with `inputs`. But for more than one expanded variable, there is a big possible error where you give the variables in the different orders in the Snakefile and `aggregate.py`. That causes a silent error where all the data is mislabeled.

Is there a canonical or recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I would better rework the *aggregate.py* script, and call it from the `shell` section. This script should not know that it is being called from Snakemake, and get all relevant information from command line. Clean interface between the caller and the script is crucial, and would help you to rethink the task itself.

Comment: That has some advantages certainly, however, I don't see how it addresses this specific concern at all. How would you solve this problem as a `shell` script?

Comment: My point is not to use `shell`. My point is that you have tightly coupled scripts that don't have an explicit api and have to know more than you can share. If you forget of Snakemake and redesign the `aggregate.py` script with explicit CLI parameters, you would automatically solve the issue.

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't think I know what you're suggesting. I always seem to have to generate the list of expanded variables at least twice, creating significant room for mistakes.